# #python3.x Importing in Shell

Tags: shell, python-3.x, import

I looked around the web, couldn't really find, guess I'm searching wrong.
I try to **import** a file I built.
In **cmd** to use it I used a cd command and and just used it.
In shell it keeps on telling me:

> [ Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in 
>       from ch09 import * ImportError: No module named 'ch09' ]

(Im just learning python my self hence *ch09*)
please if someone can help me with this, even both in cmd not to use cd, though it fine, but more important in shell).

Thanks, Josh.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be in the directory in which the file is located in order to import it from another script or from the interactive shell.

So you should either put the script trying to import `ch09` in the same folder as `ch09.py` or you should use `os.chdir` to cd to the directory internally.